# How to pipe output of net use command to file

Tags: windows, cmd, net-use

I am just getting a blank file with the following command:

```
net use \\computername password /user:username > log.txt
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `> log.txt` catches only STDOUT (Stream 1). Errors are written to `STDERR` (Stream 2). `>log.txt 2>&1` redirects STDERR to wherever `STOUT` goes (`log.txt` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Capture stderr output and check ERRORLEVEL. A `sharename` is also needed. See the output of the `NET HELP USE` command.

```
net use \\computername\sharename password /user:username >"log.txt" 2>&1
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto NetUsePassed
echo ERROR: NET USE failed.

:NetUsePassed
```

Answer (score 0):

On my PC, which I am currently logged in, I can execute...

```
net use \\localhost user:Gwen > C:\TEMP\output.txt
```

Which produces the following text in the output file...

```
The command completed successfully
```

Note that I did not pass the password to the command.

Comment: Thank you Gwen. I am wanting to use this command as a means of verifying the password in a script. Is there an alternative way I can do this?

Comment: This redirection won't work when the output is an error. You can specifiy that you want the output from both ster and stoud with 2>&1